# UITextField Delegate in UITableView

Tags: iphone, tableview

G'day guys, I'm building an application that allows users to rapidly input numbers into a `UITableView`.

I've currently built the framework, but I'm having a bit of a hitch hooking up the view to have the keyboard load and make the text in the cell editable from a user action.

I remember there being an iOS example in the dev code somewhere, (like a year ago so it wouldn't be under NDA) where you added items in and edited them within the context of the `UITableView` without going to a detailed subview.

Just need a hint on how to hook up the delegates, or how to structure the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have code where I create custom cells for a `UITableView` which have `UITextField` and `UITextView` controls on them. In the `UITableViewController` code I do this:

Interface

```
@interface MyTableViewController: 
    UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate> {
....
}
```

Implementation

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UItableView *) tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    ....

    UITableViewCell * cell = ....
    cell.myTextField.delegate = self;
    cell.myTextField.tag = 1; //This should be unique.
    return cell;
}

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField * ) textField {
    // Decide which text field based on it's tag and save data to the model.
}

-(void) textViewDidEndEditing: (UITextView * ) textView {
    // Decide which text view based on it's tag and save data to the model.
}
```

Comment: You are a SAVIOUR... ;)

Comment: Just a note guys, routing everything through the controller like this is the simple approach, but not really a good idea for anything except a simple app. You should also look into things like custom UITableViewCells and MVVM architectures.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UITextField or UITextView to any cell. If you have custom cells, make them a delegate for their text view, or if you compose the cells in your table view delegate, then make this the text fields' delegates.